# Error plotting labels gnuplot

Tags: label, gnuplot, histogram

I would like to plot this datafile

"/root/temp.txt"

```
LB|30|421
CN|50|247
BR|20|370
SA|12|310
```

Where the first column is the X Axis, the second one is the Y Axis and the third one the label to put above each column of the histogram.

Before now, I use this syntax to plot the graph (but without any label)

```
set terminal png ;
set title "Hello" ;
set xlabel "Country" ;
set ylabel "values" ;
set style fill solid ;
set xtic rotate -45 ;
set datafile separator "|" ;
set style data histograms ; 
plot '/root/temp.txt' using 2:xtic(1) notitle
```

But if I try to add labels gnu plot give me error!!

The syntax I use to add labels is
    plot '/root/temp.txt' using 2:xtic(1):3 with labels notitle

Could you please help me?
Thank you

Comment: Could you also post how you are trying to add the labels? Then it is easier to see what is going wrong.

Comment: I would like to add the label (column 3). If i try plot '/root/temp.txt' using 2:xtic(1):3 with labels notitle it makes error...!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can compress into one plotting format, but you can use `replot` (or replot-like plot):

```
plot '/root/temp.txt' using 2:xtic(1) notitle, '' u ($0):2:3 with labels notitle
```

Empty '' induce reuse the last input(file). Now, it equals with '/root/temp.txt'

[image: Solution with semi-replot]

To be nicer:

```
plot 'temp.txt' using 2:xtic(1) notitle, '' u ($0+0.1):($2+1):3 with labels notitle
```

[image: Shifted label]

**Oh! And don't forget** to `set output` of png term!